# Indesign: table borders when spanning across pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, formatting

When a table with a border but no internal row strokes breaks across pages, is there any way to automatically put a stroke below the last row before the break? Otherwise the table has borders on three sides, but is open in an ugly fashion at the page bottom?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a **Footer Row** via 'Table Options → Headers & Footers'. Then you right click any row in the table, click 'Edit Footer' and make sure you remove the top border, so only the bottom border is shown. This will repeat the 'Footer Row' as the last row in each text box, once for each page. Manually reduce the height of this 'Footer Row' to a minimum so it doesn't show up as an empty row.

[image]